# Laravel route method call works for closure function but not for Conroller@method

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

what is the difference between:

```php
Route::post('insert/{slug}/{page_number}/{person_type_id}/{user_id}', function($slug) {
    return Response::json(
    [
        'success' => false,
        'slug' => $slug
    ]);
});
```

and this:

```php
Route::post(
  '{slug}/users/page/{page_number}/insert-ben/{person_type_id}/user/{user_id}',
  'PersonsController@insertBen'
);
```

The first one works. The latter used to work but it's no longer working now. I tried stepping through the code and the latter ends up going to the `UsersController@login` rather than to `PersonsConroller@insertBen`. So odd. This was working about a month ago. I'm trying to see what I changed with my version control but it's so strange that it's not working all of a sudden.

My posts are working fine as I can login and the post call to `UsersController@doLogin` is being called.

I even tested with this call:

```php
Route::post(
  '{slug}/users/page/{page_number}/insert-ben/{person_type_id}/user/{user_id}',
  'UsersController@insertTest'
);
```

/controllers/UsersController.php

```php
public function insertTest($slug)
{
    if ( Request::ajax() ) {
        return Response::json( [

            'success' => false,
            'slug'      => $slug

        ] );
    }
}
```

But the `PersonsController@insertBen` doesn't work. My `PersonsController` is working fine as I can update using this controller. So what could be the problem? Anyone encounter something similar? Why does the route.php call the post on some of  `Controller@method` but not on others? Why does the closure function work but not the `Controller@method`?

## UPDATE

Here's the entire file. I even tested by putting that line close to the top of the file too.

```php
/** ------------------------------------------
 *  Route binding
 *  ------------------------------------------
 */
App::bind('Acme\Repositories\Interfaces\IPersonRepository', 'Acme\Repositories\Person\DbPersonRepository');
App::bind('Acme\Repositories\Interfaces\IUserRepository', 'Acme\Repositories\User\DbUserRepository');
App::bind('Acme\Repositories\Interfaces\IPage15Repository', 'Acme\Repositories\Pages\Page15Repository');

/** ------------------------------------------
 *  Route model binding
 *  ------------------------------------------
 */
Route::model('user', 'User');
Route::model('comment', 'Comment');
Route::model('post', 'Post');
Route::model('role', 'Role');

/** ------------------------------------------
 *  Route constraint patterns
 *  ------------------------------------------
 */
Route::pattern('comment', '[0-9]+');
Route::pattern('post', '[0-9]+');
Route::pattern('user', '[0-9]+');
Route::pattern('role', '[0-9]+');
Route::pattern('token', '[0-9a-z]+');


/** ------------------------------------------
 *  Admin Routes
 *  ------------------------------------------
 */
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin', 'before' => 'auth'), function()
{
    # User Management

    Route::get('users/', ['as' => 'admin.users.get.index', 'uses' => 'AdminUsersController@getIndex']);
    Route::get('users/index', ['as' => 'admin.users.get.index_page', 'uses' => 'AdminUsersController@getIndex']);
    Route::get('users/data', ['as' => 'admin.users.get.data', 'uses' => 'AdminUsersController@getData']);
    Route::get('users/{user}/edit_user_by_page/{page_number}', ['as' => 'admin.users.get.edit_user_by_page', 'uses' => 'AdminUsersController@getEditUserByPage']);

    # Admin Dashboard
    Route::get('/', 'AdminDashboardController@getIndex' );
});

// Confide routes
Route::get('users/create', ['as' => 'confide.users.get.create', 'uses' => 'UsersController@create']);
Route::post('users', ['as' => 'confide.users.post.store', 'uses' => 'UsersController@store']);
Route::get('users/login', ['as' => 'confide.users.get.login', 'uses' => 'UsersController@login']);
Route::post('users/login', ['as' => 'users.login', 'uses' => 'UsersController@doLogin']);
Route::get('users/confirm/{code}', ['as' => 'confide.users.get.confirm', 'uses' => 'UsersController@confirm']);
Route::get('users/forgot_password', [ 'as' => 'users.forgot_password', 'uses' => 'UsersController@forgotPassword' ]);
Route::post('users/forgot_password', ['as' => 'confide.users.post.forgot_password', 'uses' => 'UsersController@doForgotPassword']);
Route::get('users/reset_password/{token}', ['as' => 'confide.users.get.reset_password', 'uses' => 'UsersController@resetPassword']);
Route::post('users/reset_password', ['as' => 'confide.users.post.reset_password', 'uses' => 'UsersController@doResetPassword']);
Route::get('users/resendconfirmationemail', [ 'as' => 'users.resendconfirmationemail', 'uses' => 'UsersController@getResendConfirmationEmail' ]);
Route::post('users/resendconfirmationemail', ['as' => 'confide.users.post.resendconfirmationemail', 'uses' => 'UsersController@postResendConfirmationEmail']);
Route::get('users/logout', ['as' => 'confide.users.get.logout', 'uses' => 'UsersController@logout'])->after('invalidate-browser-cache');

/** ------------------------------------------
 *  Frontend Routes
 *  ------------------------------------------
 */

Route::get('{slug}/users/page', ['as' => 'users.page.path', 'uses' => 'UsersController@getPage'])->where('slug', '^\b(ir){0,1}(revocable){1}\b$');

//get page_number
Route::get('{slug}/users/page/{page_number}', ['before' => 'auth', 'as' => 'users.page.page_number', 'uses' => 'PersonsController@index'])->where('slug', '^\b(ir){0,1}(revocable){1}\b$');

//get edit
Route::get('{slug}/users/page/{page_number}/edit', ['before' => ['auth', 'slug' ], 'as' => 'users.page.page_number.edit', 'uses' => 'PersonsController@edit'])->where('slug', '^\b(ir){0,1}(revocable){1}\b$');

//post insert-ben
Route::post('{slug}/users/page/{page_number}/insert-ben/{person_type_id}/user/{user_id}', ['before' => 'auth', 'as' => 'users.page.page_number.insert', 'uses' => 'PersonsController@insertBen'])->where('slug', '^\b(ir){0,1}(revocable){1}\b$');

//post delete-ben
Route::post('{slug}/users/page/{page_number}/delete-ben/{person_type_id}/user/{user_id}/person_id/{person_id}/address_id/{address_id}/ben_id/{ben_id}', ['before' => 'auth', 'as' => 'users.page.page_number.delete', 'uses' => 'PersonsController@deleteBen'])->where('slug', '^\b(ir){0,1}(revocable){1}\b$');

//put update
Route::put('{slug}/users/page/{page_number}/update', ['before' => 'auth', 'as' => 'users.page.page_number.update', 'uses' => 'PersonsController@update'])->where('slug', '^\b(ir){0,1}(revocable){1}\b$');

//get upgrade page when user goes to a page like (page 17 or other pages like page 9 and 10 I think) reserved only for irrevocable registered plans. TODO: get the upgrade View model
Route::get('{slug}/users/upgrade/{_meta}', [ 'as' => 'users.ugprade', 'uses' => 'PersonsController@upgrade' ] )->where('slug', '^\b(irrevocable){1}\b$');

//Paypal post Paypal info to tables paypals, paypal_transactions, pricings and getPaypalBtn
Route::put('paypal_transactions/{slug}/{page_number}/returnpaypalbtn', ['before' => 'auth', 'as' => 'paypal_transactions.returnpaypalbtn', 'uses' => 'PaypalTransactionsController@returnPaypalBtn'])->where('slug', '^\b(ir){0,1}(revocable){1}\b$');

/** ------------------------------------------
 * Tests:
 * ------------------------------------------
 */
Route::get('users/{username}/page', ['as' => 'users.page.test', 'uses' => 'UsersController@getPageTest']);
Route::get('{slug}/users/show_sql', ['as' => 'users.page.show_sql', 'uses' => 'PersonsController@showSql'])->where('slug', '^\b(ir){0,1}(revocable){1}\b$');

# Index Page - Last route, no matches
Route::get('/', array('before' => 'detectLang', 'uses' => 'UsersController@login'));
```

Comment: you have rotues order mis match.... put the whole routes file.

Comment: As itachi said - please post your whole routes file.

Comment: Is your ajax call actually a post? And what is the error you are receiving?

Comment: @Azeame, yes, it's a post call. I have the solution below. :)

Answer (score 0):

Boy, this took a long time to figure out. Thank God! What happened was that I had this line in my `Route::filter('csrf', function()`. 
This filter is called before your other `Route::[method]` so if there are any `Route` calls in your filter like I had in mine then your defined `Route::[method]` won't be called. I think by default but not 100% sure:

`/app/filters.php`

```php
$token = Request::ajax() ? ( Request::header('X-CSRF-Token')  ) : Input::get('_token');
```

Which I ended up getting from http://words.weareloring.com/development/laravel/laravel-4-csrf-tokens-when-using-jquerys-ajax/

It was an ajax call but this `Request::header('X-CSRF-Token')` was always `null`.

So I changed that to something more readable and that works.

```php
if ( Request::ajax() )
{
    $sRequestHeaderCSRF = Request::header('X-CSRF-Token');
    if ( Request::header('X-CSRF-Token') === null || Request::header('X-CSRF-Token') === '' )
    {
        $token = Input::get('_token');
    } else
    {
        $token = Request::header('X-CSRF-Token');
    }
} else
{
    $token = Input::get('_token');
}
```

The other snag was this `Input::get('_token')` which was returning null too.

I had to pass and, explicitly, name the `_token` in the `data`. I was, previously,
passing a serialized array as the `data` in the jQuery `$.ajax`. But the calls to
get the `_token` key name from this `data` in `public function input($key = null, $default = null)`
(see below) was not retrieving it from the serialized array; hence, the explicit key being passed as 
`'_token': oSerializeArray._token`.

```js
var oSerializeArray['_token'] = $('input[name="_token"]').val();

$.ajax({
        type: action,
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        url: sUrl,
        data: {
            'oSerializeArray':  oSerializeArray,
            '_token': oSerializeArray._token
        },
        beforeSend: function() {
        }
    })
        .done( function( data, text, jqxhr ) {
            data.success;
            //data.iPersonsPK;
            window.location.replace(sUrlEdit);
        })
        .fail( function ( data, jqxhr ) {
            data.success;
        })
        .always( function ( data ) {
            data.success;
        });
```

Just fyi, `Input::get('_token')` is called from:

`/vendor/illuminate/support/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Input.php`

in this function:

```php
public static function get($key = null, $default = null)
    {
        return static::$app['request']->input($key, $default);
    }
```

and here:

`/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php:248`

in this function:

```php
public function input($key = null, $default = null)
    {
        $input = $this->getInputSource()->all() + $this->query->all();

        return array_get($input, $key, $default);
    }
```

I had to step through the code.

This is my updated `Route::filter('csrf', function()`:

```php
Route::filter('csrf', function()
{
    if ( Request::ajax() )
    {
        $sRequestHeaderCSRF = Request::header('X-CSRF-Token');
        if ( Request::header('X-CSRF-Token') === null || Request::header('X-CSRF-Token') === '' )
        {
            $token = Input::get('_token');
        } else
        {
            $token = Request::header('X-CSRF-Token');
        }
    } else
    {
        $token = Input::get('_token');
    }

    $sSessionToken = Session::token();

//if the tokens do not match then send to the login page
    if (Session::token() != $token) {
        return Redirect::to( 'users/login' );
    }
});
```

Also, more fyi, for problems with your `routes.php` one may look at these files:

`/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php`
`/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php`

and set break points while looking at your stack calls during debugging.

BTW, I read that one can use this to set the `X-CSRF token` in the headers of your `ajax` calls with this:

```js
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

The above is referenced from http://words.weareloring.com/development/laravel/laravel-4-csrf-tokens-when-using-jquerys-ajax/

I'm wondering if Taylor Otwell has some info on the architechtural design and explanations of the framework. 
I was going to read about Symfony but not sure if will help me more thoroughly understand the underpinnings of Laravel.
I know there is the Laravel API docs which is helpful but something more like a study of the design. Any ideas?